# Is there any problem with using django form just to do the validation on the server side?

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Currently the app I'm developing uses html forms and validation is done with the required value attribute. That is to say, it validates in the frontend.

However, I want to use django forms because I have heard that it is a safer way to validate information.

Reviewing the documentation seems to be something complicated to render my forms through django forms, since my forms have quite a few peculiarities in terms of design.

Considering the above, and that I already have the forms designed in html, I would like not to change them and only use django forms for validation on the server side.

**Is it possible to do this?**
**Is it a bad idea?**

Comment: you don't have to use `{{form.as_p}}` to render your django form. How you render you form in HTML doesn't really matter, so if you want to write all the HTML yourself, that's no problem at all. Yes, it's perfectly fine to use Django forms to validate (and save) the data, not to render the form. Just make sure the attributes used by your input fields correspond to the expected keys by the Django forms. (you can use `{{ form.some_field.name}}` and `{{form.some_field.id_for_label}}` to set them correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. It's common that the front end part ends up being custom due to the complexities of forms that you mentioned. The general process is that you would still validate it server side -- this is actually necessary for security -- using forms, the same way as explained in the docs, but without doing the frontend part.

So, instead of something like `{{form}}` in the template, which generates the HTML for you, you would have custom HTML.

You would then have to worry about the extra step of making sure that the name attribute of the fields matches what Django is expecting, which by default is something like `id_field_name`, but you can customize those too.